# How to use openCV in iOS? I just can't import the framework correctly

Tags: ios, xcode, opencv

How can I add opencv2 correctly to Xcode?
I just download from the website the opencv2.framework.zip， 
[image]
and then I unzip the opencv2 ,finally appears opencv2.framework.
[image]
and then I build an xcode project, choose ios single view.
[image]
then I try to add opencv2.framework to the project
[image]
then I compile the project, It shows that:
[image]
what's happening here?I'm new here and I just can't figure out a solution. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've put together a guide to use OpenCV using the .framework file (if you prefer it over cocoa pods as suggested above) you may have a look here. It works for both OpenCV2 iOS and the newer OpenCV3 iOS.

http://kurtjacobs.weebly.com/computer-vision/up-and-running-with-opencv-30-for-ios

Good luck!

Comment: there is a proble that: when I load the opencv2.framework to my xcode project, and compile, it shows "ld: framework not found opencv2
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)", why does this happen, I really don't know why and nearly be mad about it...

Comment: A couple of suggestions would be to make sure you are copying the framework file to your applications directory, i.e. when dragging it into the project ensure that you have copy items if needed selected and Create groups radio button selected and not the Create folder references radio button.

Alternatively you could also ensure that in your header search paths you have included the path for where the framework is located on disk.

Comment: I meant framework search paths and not header search paths sorry. Here is a functioning copy of a sample face detection project that you can download and run that uses the opencv.framework https://www.dropbox.com/s/89x65pwjxj0llpq/Viola-Jones%20Face%20Detect.zip?dl=0

Comment: Thank you very much! You really helps me a lot!

Comment: Hi could you please select my answer as the correct one thanks

Comment: Hi, sorry but the link no long works. Could you please put it again here? @KurtJacobs

Answer (score 0):

Try and use Cocoapods to install it. If you haven't used Cocoapods before, it is a "CocoaPods is a dependency manager for Swift and Objective-C Cocoa projects." More information is available on its website [HERE](https://cocoapods.org/).

To install OpenCV using Cocoapods, add `pod 'OpenCV'` to your pod file, and use the command `pod install`. Please refer to the OpenCV for iOS Cocoapods Readme page (https://cocoapods.org/pods/OpenCV) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the opencv2 .framework, then in Xcode project, click the targets selected build phases. Click link Binary with libraries, click add other and select the .framework, clang.